# What is the shortcut to break up multiple lines into one in sublime text 2?

Tags: shortcuts, sublime-text-2

Please browse to the [sublime text homepage](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and have a look at slide #2.

There is a "screenshot movie" showing several commands, but there is no explanation. Just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for multiple selection.

So what are the shortcuts to turn something like this

```
Mon
Tue
Wed
```

into that:

```
["Mon", "Tue", Wed"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include a link to whatever it is you want us to look at. Better yet, include the screenshot!

Comment: Well that is the link http://www.sublimetext.com/. It is the second slide im talking about. But thats a canvas, i can neither copy nor reference.

Comment: That's fine, I just did not want to have to google sublime (which I had never heard of) in order to see whether I can answer your question. The more information you include in the question and the easier you make it for people to answer, the better your chances of a good answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Type

   ```
   Mon
   Tue
   Wed
   ```
2. Select the three lines with your mouse or keyboard like you usually would do.
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will split this up into "each line individually selected by multiple cursors".
4. Press <kbd>"</kbd> which will surround each selected line with it.
5. Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the line, hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> to remove the newlines.
6. All you need to do now is type a <kbd>,</kbd>, remove the first <kbd>,</kbd> and select everything and hit <kbd>[</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can do it like in the video, but I've found that placing a comma in the beginning is much easier to accomplish since your cursor is already there.

Comment: Can you do the reverse i.e. go from "Mon", "Tue", Wed" to each in a separate line

Comment: @buffer: Yes, type `Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun`; select the first `,` and then press CTRL+D five times to select the next five commas as well, then simply press enter.

Answer (score 3):

A single command shortcut for merging multiple lines into 1 is "join lines".

1. <kbd>Command</kbd>  + J  on Mac to join lines.
2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ J on Windows
3. Edit > Lines > Join Lines

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to pushing <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> is selecting all lines to be joined and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to condense them into one line. Not sure if that was in 2, but it works great in ST3.

Comment: Nice trick! I can confirm it does work on Sublime Text 2 ;-)